# Send email to admin shopping cart data

Tags: php, html

Fist of all sorry for my bad English.
I'm using shopping cart plugin for my website (this is only example of the shopping cart) :
https://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Responsive-E-commerce-Shopping-Cart-Plugin-with-jQuery-Shopping-Mall.html

Everything is working fine except sending email to admin (in mail have to by information about sender and all shopping cart data).
So please help me i have cartform.php whit this code but i understand it's
not enough to send email.

By the way i'm form Lithuania :)

This is picture of cartform.php:

[image]

Here it look in index.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-9  col-md-10  main" id="main">
                <div class="">
                    <div id="app"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <ul id="default-item-list" class="col-md-12"></ul>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div id="detail"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

      <h2 id="basket-message" class="text-right">Jūs turite <span id="basket">0</span> prekes krepšelyje</h2>

            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 sidebar" id="sidebar">
                <table id="shopping-cart" class="table table-responsive">
                    <tbody id="shopping-list"></tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4" id="total">€ 0.00</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="showForm">Užsakyti</a>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static"
   data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

          <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Užsakymo patvirtinimas</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <form id="sendMail" action="contactform.php" method="post">
              <p>Suveskite savo duomenis, o tekso laukelyje įveskite adresą, kuriuo norite gauti prekes bei kitą svarbią informacija.</p>
            <fieldset>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                  <label for="name">Vardas:<span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control " placeholder="Jūsų vardas:" id="name" required="">
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">Laukelis tuščias arba toks negalimas</div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                  <label for="email">El. paštas:<span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control " placeholder="Jūsų el. paštas:" id="email" required="">
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">Laukelis tuščias arba toks negalimas</div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                  <label for="message">Adresas ir kita:<span>*</span></label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Įveskite tekstą:" id="message" required=""></textarea>
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">Įveskite adresą, kuriuo norite gauti prekes ir kitą svarbią informacija</div>
                  <span class="form-info"><span class="required">*</span>Įveskite adresą bei kitą svarbią informacija</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>

          <div id="thanks">
            <h1>Užsakymas įšsiųstas</h1>
            <p>Patvirtinus užsakymą su Jumis bus susisiekta dėl apmokėjimo.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.reload();">Uždaryti</a>
          </div>

        </main>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Išeiti</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="sendMailButton">Užsakyti</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

## Edit 1

but if I set `$from = "mantas34643@gmail.com";` it always be writing it send from this email or I dont understand something? Sorry I'm new in this it. I'm student and i have create website with shopping cart who will send email to admin with shopping cart data.

Comment: Is there any error? Did you checked your junk/spam folder?

Comment: By the way, I have the feeling, that you are not following the documentation for the php mail() function, Have you check this already? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php Because the arguments seems to be misplaced or missing

Comment: Code is text, not pictures. Please post the actual text of your PHP, just like you did with the HTML. There is nothing stopping you from copying and pasting it properly. Thankyou.

Comment: Anyway, it's very clear that you didn't include a "From" field in your email properties...no email can be sent without a valid From address. The examples in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) show you how to include a valid From header.

Comment: "but if I set $from = "mantas34643@gmail.com";" ...I don't understand your point. It appears you already have a $mailForm variable. This is supposed to be the person the mail is coming from, I think? You just need to include that in the  $headers variable in a valid way - again, look at the examples in the PHP documentation!

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't seems to have basic PHP mail requirements. Refer the following code:

```
$from = "yourmail@gmail.com";
$to   = "yourmail@gmail.com";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:<$from>" . "\r\nReply-to: $from";
// the message
$msg = "Mail content";

// send email
$mail_send = @mail($to,"My subject",$msg,$headers);
if($mail_send)
   echo "success";
else
   echo "error";
```